# Error during creating react native init command

Tags: javascript, react-native, templates, command-line-interface

I am new to the developing field and I planned on learning react native. I installed all the necessary components but i am getting an error when copying the template. What should I do?

```
C:\Users\hp>react-native init MovieBooking

√ Downloading template

× Copying template
error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-0lrjGr\node_modules\react-native\template.config'

Require stack:
- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\template.js

- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js

- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\index.js

- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js

- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js

- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js

- C:\Users\hp\node_modules\react-native\cli.js

- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically open terminal run a administrator  if that won't work, 
I think general problem with the latest version, Am i right you try use latest react native version?

you can try as below code;

```
npx react-native@0.60.0-rc.1 init --template=react-native@0.60.0-rc.1
```

or you wanna use typescript

also i found that's

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/issues/38

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/595

**UPDATE**

Try re-installing react-native CLI then

That's a version bug detail [this link](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/733) for solution you can downgrade you react native version before 0.60 like that

```
react-native init ProjectName --version="0.59.9"
```

Comment: It did not work. It still shows the same error and yes i was using the latest version.

Comment: can u share node and npm version

Comment: Node version-v12.8.1
Npm version-6.10.2

Comment: error Cannot use React Native CLI to initialize project with version lower than 0.60.0. 
This is what i am getting now.

Comment: Try re-installing react-native CLI

Comment: I'm happy now :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
npx react-native init yourappname --template react-native-template-typescript
```